# Need to redirect from Web appplication to Zoho Desk

Tags: .net-core

I have **Zoho desk** trail account.
We want to redirect from our web application to Z**oho Desk** Add Ticket page by clicking button.

I have configure **SAML SSO** from below mention link:

https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/kb/desk/for-administrators/user-access-and-security/articles/setting-up-saml-single-signon-for-help-center

How can i achieve this without login or auto **signup/signin** into **Zoho Desk** using **SAML SSO**?

Web application in **.net core**.

If any one have done this using code then please reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one solution for this.

Download "Component SAML" package which is paid package, but you will get 30 day trial version or Install NuGet package "ComponentSpace.saml2".

Creates a self-signed X.509 certificate.
Upload public key on Zoho Desk SAML Configuration and add private key in your project (under certificate folder).

For Dot net core application you need to add below settings in appsettings.json file.

```json
"SAML": {
  "$schema": "https://www.componentspace.com/schemas/saml-config-schema-v1.0.json",
  "Configurations": [
    {
      "LocalIdentityProviderConfiguration": {
        "LocalCertificates": [
          {
            "FileName": "certificates/idp.pfx",
            "Password": "password"
          }
        ]
      },
      "PartnerServiceProviderConfigurations": [
        {
          "Name": "{Entity Id from Zoho desk SAML Screen}",
          "SignSamlResponse": true,
          "AssertionConsumerServiceUrl": {Help Center SAML Response URL}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"ZohoDeskSettings": {
  "PartnerName": "{Entity Id from Zoho desk SAML Screen}",
  "RelayState": "{url on which you want to redirect after SSO}"
}
```

Add below code in `Startup.cs` (`ConfigurationService` method)

```cs
services.AddSaml(Configuration.GetSection("SAML"));
```

Add below code in your controller from where you will click link to redirect to zoho portal

```cs
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> InitiateSingleSignOn()
    {
        // Get the name of the logged in user.
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;

        // For demonstration purposes, include some claims.
        var attributes = new List<SamlAttribute>()
        {
            new SamlAttribute(ClaimTypes.Email, /*{Users Email}*/),
            new SamlAttribute(ClaimTypes.GivenName, /*{Users FirstName}*/),
            new SamlAttribute(ClaimTypes.Surname, /*{Users LastName}*/),
        };

        var partnerName = /*{Get setting from appsettings.json}*/;
        var relayState = /*{Get setting from appsettings.json}*/;
        
        // Initiate single sign-on to the service provider (IdP-initiated SSO)
        // by sending a SAML response containing a SAML assertion to the SP.
        // The optional relay state normally specifies the target URL once SSO completes.
        await _samlIdentityProvider.InitiateSsoAsync(partnerName, userName, attributes, relayState);

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

You can also check example provided by Component SAML